# Yahoo BOSS Placefinder inaccurate results

Tags: php, geolocation, yahoo-api

my company is using a function developped by my predecessor to geolocate an address list. However, since last week, the results returned are inaccurate not by a couple of meters but by tens or even hundreds of kilometers.

It was decided to use the Yahoo BOSS API with the PlaceFinder. Here's the function:

```
function geocode_yahoo($address,$city,$state,$country) {
    $url = "http://yboss.yahooapis.com/geo/placefinder";  
    $cc_key  = "***masked for security reason ***";  
    $cc_secret = "***masked for security reason ***";     
    $consumer = new OAuthConsumer($cc_key, $cc_secret);  
    $address = array($address, $city, $state, $country);
    $address = array_filter($address);
    $args = array();  
    $args["q"] = rawurlencode(implode(' ', $address));
    $args["flags"] = "CJ";
    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL,"GET", $url,$args);  
    $request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, NULL);  
    $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, OAuthUtil::build_http_query($args));  
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    $headers = array($request->to_header());  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
    $rsp = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($rsp != '') {
        $data = json_decode($rsp);
        if ($data && $data->bossresponse->responsecode == '200' && intval($data->bossresponse->placefinder->count)>0) {
            return (object) array('lat'=>$data->bossresponse->placefinder->results[0]->latitude, 'lng'=>$data->bossresponse->placefinder->results[0]->longitude); 
        }
    }
return false;
```

}

All the address used are canadians, and we are using the class Oauth correctly. Since last week, the results returned don't make any sense.

For example, if I enter the address: 5275 Griffith Road, Vanderhoof, BC, Canada, I have the following return from Yahoo BOSS:

```
5275 Griffith Road, Vanderhoof, BC, CANADA

{"bossresponse":{"responsecode":"200","placefinder":{"start":"0","count":"8","request":"flags=CJ&locale=CA&q=5275%2520Griffith%2520Road%252C%2520Vanderhoof%252C%2520BC%252C%2520CANADA","results":

[{"quality":"59","latitude":"-36.71462","longitude":"139.989586","offsetlat":"-36.714619","offsetlon":"139.989578","radius":"64700"},
{"quality":"59","latitude":"47.5714","longitude":"8.115335","offsetlat":"47.5714","offsetlon":"8.11533","radius":"2100"},
{"quality":"59","latitude":"51.667509","longitude":"5.375125","offsetlat":"51.667511","offsetlon":"5.37512","radius":"3900"},
{"quality":"59","latitude":"-30.832686","longitude":"-66.089954","offsetlat":"-30.832689","offsetlon":"-66.089951","radius":"30000"},
{"quality":"59","latitude":"45.965999","longitude":"14.02893","offsetlat":"45.966","offsetlon":"14.11538","radius":"13000"},
{"quality":"59","latitude":"-32.82341","longitude":"28.05365","offsetlat":"-32.82341","offsetlon":"28.05365","radius":"11200"},
{"quality":"59","latitude":"33.824049","longitude":"35.677601","offsetlat":"33.824051","offsetlon":"35.677601","radius":"1000"},
{"quality":"39","latitude":"54.014011","longitude":"-124.012894","offsetlat":"54.014011","offsetlon":"-124.012894","radius":"9600"}]}}}
```

As you can see, Yahoo BOSS found something (code 200) the quality result is low, 59 and less. In fact they are all wrong: the address is in British Columbia, but some results are getting results from Mexico. The nearest result is the last one and got a result of 39. It get the correct city but not precisely enough. It's not the only with invalid results, they are dozens other addresses with the same results.

I've tried to enter the postal code, limit the search to locale=CA, changed the format of the address, nothing could improve the result. I've tried to change the variable from $args["q"] to $args["location"], no difference in the results. I've double-checked our keys everything seems to be normal. I checked on Yahoo BOSS site to inquiry if any changes in the API occured recently, nothing. I've asked to the Yahoo Group associated with BOSS, no answer. I'm a little desperate so any help would be welcome!

Comment: I'd go yell at the yahoo people. unless their input requirements have changed drastically, there's nothing in your code that'd tell yahoo that you want mexican B.C. addresses.

Comment: Yeah, I already wrote to them, no answer. A colleague suggested to me to remove the rawurlencode and it improved the results a lot. However, I still has about 10% of results that are getting a quality of geolocation of 60% or less.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems the problem was coming from the rawurlencode which is unnecessary now with the Yahoo BOSS API. They nver answered us, but I suspect some changes in their API make this encode useless.